# Loading PNG File From Class Path Packaged in WAR File

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm trying to load a PNG file packaged in my war file so I can inline it in a email, but for the life of me I can't seem to get the paths right to get my input stream. I get the "InputStream must not be null" error on instantiation.

Project Structure:

```
src
|
---main
   |
   ---java
   |   |
   |   ---com.company.team.app_name
   |      |
   |      ---service
   |         |
   |         mailservice.java
   |
   ---resources
      |
      ---content
         |
         ---images
            |
            ---logo.png
```

paths in war file:

```
WEB-INF/classes/com/company/team/app_name/service/MailService.class
...
content/images/logo.png
```

mailservice code (in class constructor):

```
this.logoBytes = new InputStreamResource(this.getClass()
                                         .getClassLoader()
                                         .getResourceAsStream("/content/images/logo.png"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ResourceUtils` from  `org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils`;

```
try {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:content/images/logo.png")
        byte[] logoBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```